# Contenteditable divs hide content after reloading

Tags: javascript, html, css

For text editing purposes I use `contenteditable divs` in a website. When I edit some text the `div height` is growing dynamically and all other elements on the webiste below shift downwards. That's what I want. Finally I store the content via Ajax on a server. So far everything is working fine.

The problem is when I reload the content from the server the height of the `contenteditable divs` does not grow automatically to show all it's content. Instead its height stay in the initial size.

BTW, this is true for all browsers.

Does anyone have some hints to overcome this issue ?

EDIT

This is the html and javascript `contendeditable` relevant code

```
<div class="editable"    contentEditable=true  onkeyup="autoGrowSave(this)"  onblur="update(this)" ></div>

function autoGrowSave (oField) {
  if (oField.scrollHeight > oField.clientHeight) {
    oField.style.height = oField.scrollHeight + "px";
  }
  }
```

I use above javascript function to auto grow the `contenteditable`. Actually I do not know if even I need it. The jsFiddle example from Abhitalks below does not need one. Hmm ... I have to try without...

To store content on a sever I use the `onblur` attribute, which works perfect.

Comment: Where is your code and how are you loading the content back in the div? Create a small example which reproduces your problem. As far as I see, there shouldn't be any problem. See here for example - http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/6pk069ej/

Comment: Thanks for the sjfiddle example. That works perfect.  As describe above I store and retrieve content through Ajax on a server, which works fine. Just the effect of automatically sizing the `contenteditable` to show all content does not work properly. What do you mean with "where is your code" ?

Comment: Retrieving content via ajax is no different from retrieving content from elsewhere. In my example I am retrieving it from localstorage. Try entering some text along with line breaks and then save and load. The height will be adjusted to show the entire text. This is why you need to include your relevant code in the question without which, it would be nigh impossible for anyone to see what is going wrong and where.

Answer (score 0):

I answer the question myself. Thanks to Abhitaks jsFiddle I found the problem which limited to auto adjust the height. For this I appreciate the answer of course ;-)

In a CSS declaration I gave the class `editable` an initial height of 20px. Because of this the `contenteditable` could not adjust its height automatically. In turn I needed the javascript function `autoGrow()` to compensate this issue. While this "crazy" approach worked when editing the content, it did not work when reloading the content.

So the solution is to eliminate the `height`in the CSS declaration and get rid of the javascript function `autoGrow()`. Now it works perfect !